# How to make a OCSP responder?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, ocsp

I have several servers that are capable of serving *https* web pages.  Since they have certificates that are signed by my intermediate CA.  (But not Internet-facing.)

I would like to use OCSP to verify whether the certificates are active or revoked.  But all the articles I read about this, don't seem to explain things fully for my circumstance.

The openssl OCSP responder (`openssl ocsp ...`), as informed, is not a full responder, only for testing.  So I guess that I need to make one myself?  I assume that it's just a **CGI** script that verifies (with *openssl*) and prints the status.  Can someone state the requirements, or better, show me some code.
2) Can I have my *commercial web site*, governed by my ISP, employ this script, even though it's shared hosting?  I guess I can put the CGI in a certain directory, then have the certificates employ the x509 extension specifying the OCSP URI.

Then each server could use stapling and attach the certificate status.

It seems I need a responder that checks the intermediate certificate with the index of the rootCA and have the intermediate certificate use this URI.  Also a responder to verify each server certificate with the index of the intermediate certificate.  So another question, can these use the same host with different URIs?  Does it matter the *commercial web host* is not certified?

Comment: If you just want to have something to use in OCSP stapling then using `openssl ocsp` as responder should be sufficient - the server will only query the responder from time to time. If you something accessible to clients you might still use `openssl ocsp` as responder in the backend but then you should cache the response instead of querying the responder every time. And you might need to translate between a OCSP GET request and a POST request since `openssl ocsp` responder supports only the latter - see  [here](https://gist.github.com/vanbroup/fce08e33b4a5ee80e3b24ac4a1b065cf) for an example.

Comment: As for all your other sub question - this question is already too broad in my opinion. I recommend that you start based on my last comment and ask very specific questions if you run into problems.